# How does python inheritance work with GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, inheritance, webapp2

So, I have wasted now about two hours in a bug that I assume has to do with inheritance problems in python and GAE.

I have 2 classes, `BlogHandler`, and the child, `LoginHandler`:

```
    class BlogHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):    
        def __init__(self, request=None, response=None):
            super(BlogHandler, self).__init__(request, response)
            self.is_logged_in = False

        def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
            webapp2.RequestHandler.initialize(self, *args, **kwargs)
            logging.warning('Checking for cookie')

            if True:
                self.is_logged_in = True
                logging.warning('We are logged in!')
            else:
                logging.warning('We seem to be logged out')

    class LoginHandler(BlogHandler):    
        def get(self):
            logging.warning('Choose wisely!: + %s', self.is_logged_in)
            if self.is_logged_in:
                self.redirect(MAIN_URL)
            else:
                self.render("login.html")
```

Every time I get a GET request from a client, the `initialize(self, *args, **kwargs)` method will run in the father, and then the `get(self):` method will run on the child.

Now I want the father to share a variable with the child, the `is_logged_in` variable. I have to give a default value to the varible so I initialize it in the father's constructor as `False`

Then, when I run the `initialize(self, *args, **kwargs)` I check for a condition, which is always `True`, so it has 100% chance of changing the `is_logged_in` variable to `True`.

Back to the child, I check the value of the said variable and ... **is is always False**. I cannot understand this bug, specially because I know I am changing the value of the said variable. Here is a log:

```
WARNING  2014-05-09 22:50:52,062 blog.py:47] Checking for cookie
WARNING  2014-05-09 22:50:52,062 blog.py:51] We are logged in!
WARNING  2014-05-09 22:50:52,063 blog.py:116] Choose wisely!: + False
INFO     2014-05-09 22:50:52,071 module.py:639] default: "GET /blog/login HTTP/1.1" 200 795
```

Why is this happening? What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
class BlogHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request=None, response=None):
        self.is_logged_in = False
        super(BlogHandler, self).__init__(request, response)
```

Putting your attribute before your call to super.

Comment: Wait ... WHAT!? It worked ... HOW?! What kind of sorcery is this? Can you give me a link or some explanation to why this works now ?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix, I was going to edit my answer but Tim Hoffman beat me to it. Sorry, I was  heading out when I answered your question so it is lacking a bit of depth.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer provided fixes it for you, but doesn't explain why.

This has nothing to do with GAE, or failure in python inheritance.

In your case the `__init__` method is inherited by LoginHandler and always sets `is_logged_in` to `False` after the `super` call.  This is expected behaviour of inheritence.

You problem is you are calling `super` in your `__init__` before you set `is_logged_in`, which means whatever you do in your own `initialize` method you are immediately and unconditionally overriding it.

Comment: I was about to  edit my answer to explain why, I don't think it is necessary now after your explanation?

Comment: Damn... I come from Java. In there the super method (father constructor) always has to be the first line. I guess here things work differently. Thx !

Comment: If you look at the example in the docs, they don't even call super, they just say call `initialize` explicitly.